# change color on content scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the color of the header thing when a div has been scrolled down, below is my code.

html

```
<h1 class="theheader">The Header</h1>
<div class="tablelimiter">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>column 3</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>row 1 in column 1</td>
                <td>row 1 in column 2</td>
                <td>row 1 in column 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 2 in column 1</td>
                <td>row 2 in column 2</td>
                <td>row 2 in column 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 3 in column 1</td>
                <td>row 3 in column 2</td>
                <td>row 3 in column 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 4 in column 1</td>
                <td>row 4 in column 2</td>
                <td>row 4 in column 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 5 in column 1</td>
                <td>row 5 in column 2</td>
                <td>row 5 in column 3</td>
            </tr>
        <tbody>
    <table>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.tablelimiter{overflow: auto; height: 300px;}
```

and I'm using slimScroll

```
//add slim scroll for the table limiter
$('.tablelimiter').slimScroll({
    height: '200px',
    alwaysVisible: true,
    allowPageScroll: false,
    railVisible: true

});
```

and those works nice. Now what I want is when the `.tablelimiter` content (this set to `overflow: auto` so that there is a scrollbar stuff) has been scroll down, I want the `.theheader` (h1, the header) to change color to red. How to do that? any help, suggestions, ideas, recommendations, clues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this to give you the result you want

```
$('.tablelimiter').scroll(function(e) { 
    $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ? 
        $('.theheader').addClass('red') : 
        $('.theheader').removeClass('red');
});
```

---

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/936wcuh5/) - scroll to bottom for `.ready` code

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you can add a listener to check if the top/bottom was reached:

```
$('.tablelimiter').slimScroll({
    height: '200px',
    alwaysVisible: true,
    allowPageScroll: false,
    railVisible: true
}).bind('slimscroll', function(e, pos){
    if(pos == "bottom")
        $('.theheader').css('color', 'red');
    else // if (pos == "top")
        $('.theheader').css('color', 'black');
});
```